# FluentValidation SetValidator not called when property is null

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have a few custom validators that I attach to fields using the `RuleFor(o => o.property).SetValidator(new CustomValidator())` syntax.

Here is an example:

```
public class BankRoutingNumberValidator : AbstractValidator<string?>
{
    public BankRoutingNumberValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(routingNumber => routingNumber)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Bank Routing Number is required.")
            .Length(9).WithMessage("Bank Routing Number must be 9 digits.")
            .Matches(@"^\d{9}$").WithMessage("Bank Routing Number must be 9 digits.")
            .Must(HaveValidChecksum).WithMessage("Bank Routing Number is not valid. Please verify and re-enter.");
    }

    private static bool HaveValidChecksum(string routingNumber)
    {
        // I know, this should be superfluous
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(routingNumber)  || routingNumber.Length != 9) return false;

        int[] digits;
        try
        {
            digits = routingNumber.ToCharArray()
                .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var checksum = 3 * (digits[0] + digits[3] + digits[6]) 
                       + 7 * (digits[1] + digits[4] + digits[7]) 
                       + (digits[2] + digits[5] + digits[8]);
        return checksum % 10 == 0;
    }
}
```

I set this up in my parent validator as follows:

```
RuleFor(payment => payment.RoutingNumber)
    .SetValidator(new BankRoutingNumberValidator());
```

When the routing number is an empty string, is less than 9 digits, includes non-digits, or does not checksum, this validator works perfectly.  However, if the routing number is null, the custom validator is not called.  I have to add an explicit null check to the parent validator.

```
RuleFor(payment => payment.RoutingNumber)
    .SetValidator(new BankRoutingNumberValidator())
    .NotNull();
```

That addition does not seem right because it forces you to apply "Required" criteria outside of the custom validator.  It makes more sense to allow the custom validator to be self-contained, including null and empty checks. However, I could not find a way to get the null check inside the custom validator working.

Is that "as designed" for FluentValidation?

Comment: FYI, I tried overriding PreValidate, as mentioned in some other posts, but when the property value (InstanceToValidate) is null, PreValidate did not get called either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [@JeremySkinner's comment](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/582#issuecomment-334434724)

> If you use SetValidator with an AbstractValidator derivative, then it will not be run if the property value is null. This is intentional behaviour as AbstractValidator derivatives are designed to validate the properties of a complex type, which cannot be done if the instance is null.

That is the reason why the `HaveValidChecksum` custom validator is not triggered when the value is `null`.

And he proposes either:

1. Use the `.NotNull()` built-in validator as your second approach. You may apply the `.NotNull()` rule in `BankRoutingNumberValidator` instead of in the root model constructor.

```cs
RuleFor(routingNumber => routingNumber)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
    .NotNull().WithMessage("Bank Routing Number is required.")  // Add NotNull() rule here
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Bank Routing Number is required.")
    .Length(9).WithMessage("Bank Routing Number must be 9 digits.")
    .Matches(@"^\d{9}$").WithMessage("Bank Routing Number must be 9 digits.")
    .Must(HaveValidChecksum).WithMessage("Bank Routing Number is not valid. Please verify and re-enter.");
```

2. Implement a validator with `PropertyValidator</* Your model */, string>` type instead of `AbstractValidator`. However, this will result in you not being able to use the built-in validator here.

```cs
public class BankRoutingNumberValidator : PropertyValidator<BankingModel, string>
{
    public BankRoutingNumberValidator() 
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(ValidationContext<BankingModel> context, string value) 
    {
        return HaveValidChecksum(value);
    }

    public override string Name => "RoutingNumber";

    protected override string GetDefaultMessageTemplate(string errorCode)
        => "Bank Routing Number is not valid. Please verify and re-enter.";
        

    private static bool HaveValidChecksum(string routingNumber)
    {
        // Your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K0LBZn)

Comment: Thank you. I previously tried the PropertyValidator, but your example is MUCH clearer than the documentation and it allowed me to get it working.